# Query distinct row value and separate into different columns

Tags: sql, pivot, sybase

I have a table which has the following content:

```
Customer ID             Customer type                
---------               --------
123                        A
123                        alpha
123                        Beta   
456                        B
456                        BGamma
456                        BBeta
```

I want to achieve the following:

```
Customer_ID    Customer_type     Customer_E1    Customer E_2   Customer E_3 
---------      -----------       -----------    -------------  -------------
123                 A               Alpha          Beta
456                 B               BGamma         BBeta
```

Can you please help me with a Sybase query to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe Sybase has a `PIVOT` function which is what you are trying to do. So you might be able to implement something like this which uses an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement:

```
select customerid,
  max(case when rn = 1 then customertype else null end) CustomerType,
  max(case when rn = 2 then customertype else null end) Customer_E1,
  max(case when rn = 3 then customertype else null end) Customer_E2
from
(
  select CustomerID, CustomerType,
    row_number() over(partition by CustomerID order by CustomerID) rn
  from yourtable
) src
group by customerid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/63d02/2)

*Note:* I see a potential issue with the first column of data `CustomerType`. My suggestion would be to have this in a separate column from the other values.  Then this will not take part in the `row_number()` assignment and it will be easier to guarantee that the correct value will appear.

Comment: you are using a row_number() function here. I've got Sybase 11. Will this work in Sybase ASE 11.

Comment: @user726720 if you do not have `row_number()` then you might be able to do this with a series of joins.  I will try to post a version a little later

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest that you normalize your data model.  Clearly 'A' vs 'Alpha' are different kinds of data values (they describe different things), but you have them in the same field, which is causing you all sorts of problems.  Take a [look at this article on database normalization](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/An-Introduction-to-Database-Normalization/), which has a good discussion of the concepts involved.

Basically, what you want to end up with is having alpha and beta type values in a separate table that you can key into via Customer ID and Customer Type.

Comment: this was an example of what I'm trying to achieve on a live database. My live db is completely normalized. Do you have any other sugesstions on how to go about the above problem ?

Comment: So, because it's a live database, I get that you may not have the freedom to fix the normalization issue. But even if the rest of the db is well-normalized the way [Customer type] is being used is not normalized.  That's why you have multiple entries in this table for customers such as 123.

Comment: If Sybase has PIVOT, you could use that.